# Are Asians more genetically homogenous than other races?

Tags: genetics

I've heard that Asians (I'm not entirely sure which subgroup was being referred to) tend to be more genetically homogenous than other races, with people of African lineage being on the other end of the spectrum being the least homogenous.

Is there any truth in the claim that Asians or a specific subcategory such as South East Asians have less genetic variance than other races?

I've seen papers like [Extreme mtDNA homogeneity in continental Asian populations](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12012367) for example, but I don't understand enough to know if that answers my question.

If Asians have less genetic variance, would that lead to less variance in phenotypes?

Comment: I think you'll find that Africans are the most genetically heterogeneous.

Comment: @AlanBoyd That's interesting...do you have a source? I remembered reading it was Caucasians which given how far Caucasians have spread and evolved independently would make sense to me...

Comment: This Wikipedia page is a good source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_genetic_variation The argument is that during the out-of-Africa migrations only a small sample of the total genetic variation left Africa. Those who remained inherited all of the existing variation. Detailed information at the WP page.

Answer (score 6):

I will side-step the question of 'race', as you seem to be using it (like most people) in the sense that has no scientific basis, but the answer to your question goes something like this:

The amount of genetic variation in a given population is mostly the function of the geographical distance from Africa. Roughly, populations in Africa are most genetically variable as they are the oldest (they have been there for the longest time in human evolutionary history and therefore there was a long time for mutations to accumulate in their genomes). Because all the other populations in the world have originated from these original African populations, they have a subset of that original variation - they are less variable. The further you get from Africa the less variation remains (a very simplistic scenario: a group of Africans left and settled down in the Middle East; then a group of Middle Easterners went further up to Europe and further east to India; then the Indians moved further north and east etc. etc.; in each stage, only a subset of the previous variation would be travelling along).

A famous image depicting this phenomenon is in Ramachandran, S. et al. (2005). Support from the relationship of genetic and geographic distance in human populations for a serial founder effect originating in Africa. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America, 102(44), 15942–15947. doi:10.1073/pnas.0507611102 figure 1B

[image: [Source](http://www.pnas.org/content/102/44/15942)]

On the Y axis you have a measure of genetic relatedness (more relatedness = less variation) and on the X axis you have rough geographic distance that takes into account major geographic barriers (like seas etc.). Green is Eurasia and blue is Australia and Oceania. Red is variation within the groups (so, Europeans only, Australians only etc.) The variation  between the populations explained by this geographic distance is close to 80% - which is huge. If I get this right, it means that most of the genetic differences between people in different populations are a simple consequence of living outside Africa. And the variation within each population is tiny (12%) compared to the between population.

This is a simplified view, because we now know that there were other species of humans that lived when our ancestors left Africa, and that thay had sex together as our ancestors spread around the globe, so a small portion of the others' DNA is still present in us today. Also this picture may be slightly different depending on what region of the genome you're looking at. But the major picture stands.

Going back to your question - "Asians" (populations with ancestry in east Asia) are on average more genetically homogenous than "Australians", "Americans", and "Africans".

EDIT: A paper I like that should explain all this much better: Barbujani, G., & Colonna, V. (2010). Human genome diversity: frequently asked questions. Trends in genetics : TIG, 26(7), 285–295. doi:10.1016/j.tig.2010.04.002 [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952510000788)

Comment: a sensible , scientific answer to a sensitive question!

Comment: Thankyou, a very interesting answer! I disagree that race has no scientific basis as I think that's being overly PC. Could you clarify if on your last point when you say "Australians" or "Americans" you mean Caucasians, or if you actually mean Australians or Americans?

Comment: Answering the second part of the question: I mean people of Australian or American ancestry. The first part: I encourage you to read that Barbujani paper. When people say "race" they tend to mean a social construct that classifies people into groups based on physical appearance (skin color, hair, eyes etc.). You cannot divide people like that based on the DNA, because the variation is continuous and all division of it will be arbitrary. It's like seeing a rainbow: can you tell me exactly where the yellow ends and orange begins?

Comment: The reason I think it's being overly PC to assume race has no biological basis is because we have evidence to the contrary. When people say Caucasians or Asians or Black, we genrally know what the people being referred to look alike. That aside, there are different medical issues effecting different races. Race is the subgrouping of people with common characteristics, which we know exists in biology. That's all it has to be, unless you make it into something more. Koreans all have genetic characteristics in common that Caucasians lack, and vice versa. No?

Comment: I think your answer would be a lot more useful if You didn't compare races to nationalities, especially nationalities only established in the last half century. Would you say the Asian Race is more genetically homogenous than the Caucasian Race? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_race and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoloid_race

Comment: @SonnyOrdell No. I agree that when people say Asians or Black, we generally know what they mean - because we tend to think in general features of appearance. This may be particularly true in the US, where the people of many greatly different ancestries live together (imagine picking only "full" colours from the rainbow). But the gradients are there - in physical appearence and in DNA. And "what people look alike" is just adaptation to the environment (ie skin color is an adaptation to uv radiation). Anwyay, this comment section is probably not a best place for a complex discussion...

Comment: @yotiao would you be interested in taking it to chat? My point I guess is that the phenotypes we associate with cultural constructs have a basis in DNA..gradients are there, but I don't see why that takes away from it. If we study ancient human remains we can see the remains, can we not?

Comment: I'm still interested in how Asian genetic homogeneity compares to Caucasian genetic homogeneity, outside of Americans and Australians.

Comment: Fine with chat - but I don't know how, I've never used it :-) Give me some time to find relevant papers and we can talk.

Comment: @yotiao I've been busy, sorry for the late reply. You still down to chat?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell I am, probably later today. My local time is GMT. I think we may do it there: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11814/genetic-variation-in-humans

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry, caucasians all look the same to Asians too. This is because of the [cross-race effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-race_effect): we are able to effectively distinguish people we are more familiar with.

But as for the most genetically diverse race, [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_genetics) might be of interest: "Sub-Saharan Africans have greater genetic diversity than other populations." The research paper the quotation is based on is found [here](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/62133/21011_ftp.pdf?sequence=1).

To be honest, I don't see the point of this question. The answer depends on what classifies under a race: Do Asians include Indians? What qualifies as Caucasian? etc.

The only thing that can be gained by exploring race-specific genetic distinctions is if you want to promote some racial supremist attitude like that guy with the toothbrush mustache.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the tired of argument of whether or not race is a valid construct, and I don't see it as relevant to the question. For most people outside of the UK, Asians refers to the peoples of the Asian continent..Chinese, Japanese, Koreans, Thai etc..

Comment: The point of the question is that I was curious about it and wanted a detailed answer after being unable to find one myself...isn't that part of why sites like this exist? The cross-race effect is interesting, but doesn't address the question. I'm not asking about the most genetically diverse race, and I think it's naive to say exploring race-specific genetic distinctions is only useful for promoting racial supremacy.